# Селектор по первому значению

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

Есть дом:

```
<h1>
 "value_1"
 <span>value_2</span>
</h1>
```

Нужно написать селектор который выберет только значение `value_1`.

`value_1` и `value_2` меняются.

Мои попытки:

```
//div[@class="product-info"]//h1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodes = document.querySelector("h1").childNodes; // Берем дочерные "узлы"
nodes.filter = [].filter; // Крадем функцию фильтрации из масива
nodes.filter((n) => n.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE); // Фильтруем
console.log(nodes[0]); //"value_1"
```